# "Buying a car" Ruby codewars

Tags: ruby

I am trying to do Ruby codewars challenge and I am stuck since I pass sample tests but can't pass final one. I am getting error Expected: [8, 597], instead got: [8, 563].

> **Instructions :**
>
> A man has a rather old car being worth $2000. He saw a secondhand car
>   being worth $8000. He wants to keep his old car until he can buy the
>   secondhand one.
>
> He thinks he can save $1000 each month but the prices of his old car
>   and of the new one decrease of 1.5 percent per month. Furthermore the
>   percent of loss increases by a fixed 0.5 percent at the end of every
>   two months.
>
> Example of percents lost per month:
>
> If, for example, at the end of first month the percent of loss is 1,
>   end of second month percent of loss is 1.5, end of third month still
>   1.5, end of 4th month 2 and so on ...
>
> Can you help him? Our man finds it difficult to make all these
>   calculations.
>
> How many months will it take him to save up enough money to buy the
>   car he wants, and how much money will he have left over?

```
def nbMonths(startPriceOld, startPriceNew, savingperMonth, percentLossByMonth)
  months = 0
  leftover = 0
  currentSavings = 0
  until (currentSavings + startPriceOld) >= (startPriceNew)
    months += 1
    months.even? ? percentLossByMonth = percentLossByMonth + 0.5 : percentLossByMonth
    startPriceNew = startPriceNew * (1 - (percentLossByMonth/100))
    startPriceOld = startPriceOld * (1 - (percentLossByMonth/100))
    currentSavings = currentSavings + savingperMonth
  end
  leftover = currentSavings + startPriceOld - startPriceNew
  return [months, leftover.abs.to_i]
end
```

I don't want to look at solutions and I don't need one here just a nudge in the right direction would be very helpful.

Also, I get that code is probably sub-optimal in a lot of ways but I have started coding 2 weeks ago so doing the best I can.

Tnx guys

Comment: Just to know, url of this kata?

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/554a44516729e4d80b000012/train/ruby

Answer (score 3):

Your algorithm is good. But you have two coding  errors:

1) `percentLossByMonth` needs to be converted to float before dividing it by 100 ( 5 / 100 = 0 while (5.to_f) / 100 = 0.05 )

2) It's said in the instructions that you need to return the nearest integer of the leftover, which is `leftover.round`

```
def nbMonths(startPriceOld, startPriceNew, savingperMonth, percentLossByMonth)
  months = 0
  leftover = 0
  currentSavings = 0
  until (currentSavings + startPriceOld) >= (startPriceNew)
    months += 1
    percentLossByMonth += months.even? ? 0.5 : 0    
    startPriceNew = startPriceNew * (1 - (percentLossByMonth.to_f/100))
    startPriceOld = startPriceOld * (1 - (percentLossByMonth.to_f/100))
    currentSavings += savingperMonth
  end
  leftover = currentSavings + startPriceOld - startPriceNew
  return [months, leftover.round]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code has been identified, so I will just offer an alternative calculation.

```
r = 0.015
net_cost = 8000-2000
n = 1
months, left_over = loop do
  r += 0.005 if n.even?
  net_cost *= (1-r)
  tot = n*1000 - net_cost
  puts "n=#{n}, r=#{r}, net_cost=#{net_cost.to_i}, " +
    "savings=#{(n*1000).to_i}, deficit=#{-tot.to_i}"
  break [n, tot] if tot >= 0
  n += 1
end
  #=> [6, 766.15...]
months
  #=> 6
left_over
  #=> 766.15...
```

and prints

```
n=1, r=0.015, net_cost=5910, savings=1000, deficit=4910
n=2, r=0.020, net_cost=5791, savings=2000, deficit=3791
n=3, r=0.020, net_cost=5675, savings=3000, deficit=2675
n=4, r=0.025, net_cost=5534, savings=4000, deficit=1534
n=5, r=0.025, net_cost=5395, savings=5000, deficit=395
n=6, r=0.030, net_cost=5233, savings=6000, deficit=-766
```